# Jquery Undefined for Telerik grid

Tags: jquery, for-loop, telerik, grid, undefined

I am getting javascript error "JQuery undefined" for telerik grid implementation, I dont understand the reason for the same. I did include all the possible JQuery files but still getting the Javascript error.

Below is the sample code I have implemented.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Employee)
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
                                                .Name("Employee")
                                                .DataKeys(keys =>
                                                {
                                                    keys.Add(m => Id);

                                                })

                                                .Columns(columns =>
                                                {

                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name")
                                                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "110px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "110px", style = "text-align:left;height:auto" });
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.ReportedStatus).ClientTemplate("<#= ReportedStatus(data) #>").Title("Reported")
                                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "130px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "130px", style = "text-align:center;height:auto" });
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("status").ClientTemplate("<#=status(data) #>")
                                                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "130px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "130px", style = "text-align:center;height:auto" });
                                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Hrs).Title("Hrs")
                                                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "150px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "150px", style = "text-align:center;height:auto" });
                                                    columns.Bound(l => l.Location).ClientTemplate("<#= Location(data) #>").Title("Location")
                                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "200px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "200px", style = "text-align:center;height:auto" });
                                                    columns.Bound(l => l.Role).ClientTemplate("<#= Role(data) #>").Title("Role")
                                                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { width = "150px", style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold;height:auto" })
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { width = "150px", style = "text-align:center;height:auto" });

                                                }).Footer(false)
                                                                          )
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.common.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.textbox.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.grid.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.draganddrop.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.window.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.grid.editing.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.upload.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/telerik.menu.js")"></script>

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                 .jQuery(false)
                 .DefaultGroup(group => group
                 .Add("telerik.examples.min.js")
                 .Add("telerik.grid.js")
                 .Compress(false)
                 .Combined(true))
                 .OnDocumentReady(
                 @<text> prettyPrint();
</text>)
)
```

Please let me know what wrong I am doing out here for this JQuery error.

Thanks in Advance,
Maanoj

Comment: Please indent your code in a way that people are able to read it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not including the files properly . If you have Double Quotes inside your string the parser thinks its the end of the string and not interpret the string properly. You need to either escape them or  use **single Quotes** inside instead..

Instead of

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"
```

Try

```
src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js')"

         OR
src="@Url.Content(\"~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js\")"
```

You can also achieve the same by escaping the double Quotes because the parser may think it's end of a string that comes between " "

Comment: Sushanth - I tried both the above options but none of them are working and getting the build error of "Too many character in character literal".